# Installing rstan on a cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, stan, rstan

When installing rstan on a cluster, how should one go about choosing the number of cores to use for the build (in the line `Sys.setenv(MAKEFLAGS = "-j4"` described in the [documentation](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started))? If each node in the cluster has 16 cores, does it make sense to set the value to 16? What if a user wants to run stan across multiple nodes with MPI? Or does it make the most sense to keep the value at 4 in any case, since most people will be running no more than 4 chains in parallel anyway? I would really appreciate any advice on this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, I answered John's question when he posted it on the Stan-users mailing list. In short, it does not matter how many cores are used at build time, you can use any number of cores at run time using any parallel scheme supported by R (or any of the other interfaces to Stan).